# How to get data into an EXTJS Grid Panel using json and sql

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, gridview, extjs

I am trying to display a gridview in extjs. That data is collected from sql db. I have a query to get the data from sql db in my GridViewController() but I am not sure on how to save those data in an array and then encode it as JSON and send the data back.

my gridviewcontroller

```
public string writeRecord()
    {

        Response.Write("Survey Completed!");
        SqlConnection conn = DBTools.GetDBConnection("ApplicationServices2");


        string sqlquery = "SELECT Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Improvements, Comments FROM myTable";
        SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery, conn);

        DataSet myData = new DataSet();
        cmd.Fill(myData, "myTable");

        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = jss.Serialize(myData);

        conn.Open();
        conn.Close();
        return "{rows: '+ json +'}";

    }
```

and this is my gridviewApp.js. This is where I create the gridview and try to get the data back from my gridviewController.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {


        storeId: 'myData',
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            fields:[
            { name: 'Q1', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'Q2', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'Q3', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'Q4', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'Q5', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'Improvements', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'Comments', type: 'string'}]
            }),

            proxy: {
            type: 'json',
            url: 'GridView/writeRecord'
            }

    });  
    this.grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title: 'GridView App',
        url: 'GridView/writeRecord',
        //store: store,
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('myData'),
        columns: [
        {header: 'Q1', width: 100,
        sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Q1'},
        { header: 'Q2', width: 100,
            sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Q2'
        },
        { header: 'Q3', width: 100,
            sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Q3'
        },
        { header: 'Q4', width: 100,
            sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Q4'
        },
        { header: 'Improvements', width: 200,
            sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Improvements'
        },
        { header: 'Comments', width: 200,
            sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Comments'
        }
    ],
        stripeRows: true,
        //height:250,
        width: 800,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```

Any kind of suggestion or input will be highly appreciated... thanks

***Update guys:***

I get this error 
A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo'.

when I use

```
return Json(myData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

But I am able to get result from my db when I use

```
myData.GetXml();
```

And here's another tricky part.
I can only access my db result using direct path like

```
http://localhost:55099/GridView/writeRecord
```

but my gridView.js still shows blank... any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use MVC's built in Json functionality like this:

```
    public ActionResult ActionName()
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        // populate ds

        return Json(ds, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

This will ensure your Json comes out in the right format.

**EDIT**

Your function would look like this:

```
    public ActionResult writeRecord()
    {

        Response.Write("Survey Completed!");
        SqlConnection conn = DBTools.GetDBConnection("ApplicationServices2");


        string sqlquery = "SELECT Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Improvements, Comments FROM myTable";
        SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery, conn);

        DataSet myData = new DataSet();
        cmd.Fill(myData, "myTable");


        conn.Open();
        conn.Close();

        return Json(myData, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your input doug... in tried to implement that into my writeRecord()... instead of returns {rows: '+ json +'} into return Json(myData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); but i get error saying 'cannot implicitly convert type system.web.mvc.jsonresult to string.

Comment: That's because the return type of your writeRecord() function is 'string' you want to return an ActionResult, or JsonResult.

Comment: sweet... thanks that took care of that error... but now my gridview shows nothing...

Comment: What does the Json look like when it's returned? You need to make sure it's in a format your store will understand

Comment: Doug, my firebug does not have any Json option where i can find the json result. Am I calling the controller right?

Comment: You should still be able to see the raw data in the response section. Try Chrome or fiddler2 if you still cannot see it. Once your json is correct... use the root config property of the jsonreader to point to your rows array. Thats the root node where the data for your store is to begin the load from.

Comment: Thanks Tim but it's not on my response too.. pls check this http://tinypic.com/r/25po3sg/6

Comment: Well, tbh I cannot tell if you are even calling your web method. Your code sample is using a custom object; i'd stick with a basic grid object first, and detach it from the extended webviewapp object initially.