# Return count and data as json into extjs grid

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, count, json

How can I return two `Json` objects? Basically I am trying to send bunch of datas from sql db and the number of rows in the db.

The below code sends `myData` successfully, but now I would also like to send `count`.

```
string sqlquery = "SELECT Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Improvements, Comments FROM myTable";
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery, conn);
SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn);
DataSet myData = new DataSet();
cmd.Fill(myData, "myTable");


comd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable";
Int32 count = (Int32)comd.ExecuteScalar();

comd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myData, Formatting.Indented,
                        new JsonSerializerSettings
                        {
                            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                        });
```

this is my grid

```
this.grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title: 'GridView App',
        frame: true,
        trackMouseOver: true,
        disableSelection: true,
        autoHeight: true,
        store: store,
        loadMask: true,
        columns: [

        { header: 'Q1',
            sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Q1'
        },
        { header: 'Q2',
            sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Q2'
        },
        { header: 'Q3',
            sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Q3'
        },
        { header: 'Q4',
            sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Q4'
        },
        { header: 'Improvements', flex: 1,
            sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Improvements'
        },
        { header: 'Comments', flex: 1,
            sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Comments'
        }
    ],
```

and this is my store...

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {

        storeId: 'myData',
        scope: this,
        pagesize: itemsPerPage,
        remoteSort: true,
        fields: [
    { name: 'Q1', type: 'int' },
    { name: 'Q2', type: 'int' },
    { name: 'Q3', type: 'int' },
    { name: 'Q4', type: 'int' },
    { name: 'Q5', type: 'int' },
    { name: 'Improvements', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'Comments', type: 'string' }
    ],

        sorters: [
        {
            property: 'Q1',
            direct: 'ASC'
        }
     ],

        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            scope: this,
            url: 'GridView/writeRecord',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'myTable',
                totalProperty: 'count'
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: wait, are you doing that on the controller? I usually return a list from controller to the view through Json, I just type return Json(theList). I guess it is returing the dataset as json but probably you need to dig in in the return to find the data from database, since it is more complex(more layers ) than a simple generic list

Comment: Hi Edwin... i am using json.net serialization... i have an extjs gridview, which uses this controller... here is the original post....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12587799/extjs-gridview-shows-no-data... and yes it is returning my dataset as json... but I'd definitely would like to try your suggestion... could you please explain a little on how I go about doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, basically, how i do it in my ASP.NET apps, i'm also using JSON.NET:

```
string sqlquery = "SELECT Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Improvements, Comments FROM myTable";
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery, conn);
SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn);
DataSet myData = new DataSet();
cmd.Fill(myData, "myTable");


comd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pid_FluSurvey";
Int32 count = (Int32)comd.ExecuteScalar();

comd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new { myTable = myData.Tables[0], count = count }, Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    });
```

What is important here is that you can call `SerializeObject` on any anonymous type and put there any number of propertys you want/need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer VoidMain... I got both the values in Json, but now it created another column header(it created a layer) http://i46.tinypic.com/14t5x0z.jpg... so my reader can't access "myTable"... is there a fix for that?

Comment: I also updated my original post with my store and grid method, where you can see how I pull data from Json

Answer (score 0):

here it is how I do, I use it for all my mvc apps. I found this example on the internet(I changed it a little bit), since I am at the office and work only with webforms here(I know... that's bad, when you go mvc you never go back)

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }


public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public List<Person> personList = new List<Person>{ 
                                                        new Person{ Name="Jpnh", Surname="Coco"},
                                                        new Person{ Name="Mike", Surname="Nile"}  
                                                      };

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }



        public ActionResult GetData()
        {

            return Json(personList);
        }

}

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#button').click(GetValue);

        });

        function GetValue() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/GetData",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data[0].Name);
                }

            });

        };

    </script>
```

The code by itself is very intuitive to understand and I am assuming you have no problems filling out a Generic list from database

let me know