# Extjs Grid Paging Toolbar Shows All Data and No Page Number

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs, grid, paging, toolbar

I am using extjs paging toolbar on my grid. I have pagesize 5, but it shows all data(default is I guess 25)... but when I click next page, it still shows the first 25 data. and also have issue with page number where it's blank of 2...when it's suppose to say 1 of 2... [Click here to see what it looks like](http://i48.tinypic.com/ofpu14.jpg)

this is my grid...

```
var myPageSize = 5;
store.load({
    params: {
        start: 0,
        limit: myPageSize
    }
});
this.grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'GridView App',
    store: store,
    loadMask: true,
    columns: [{
        header: 'Q1',
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'Q1',
        flex: 1,
    }, {
        header: 'Q2',
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'Q2',
        flex: 1,
    }, {
        header: 'Q3',
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'Q3',
        flex: 1,
    }, {
        header: 'Q4',
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'Q4',
        flex: 1,
    }, {
        header: 'Improvements',
        flex: 1,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'Improvements'
    }, {
        header: 'Comments',
        flex: 1,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'Comments'
    }],

    bbar: Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
        style: 'border:1px solid #99BBE8;',
        store: store,
        displayInfo: true,
        preprendButtons: true,
        displayMsg: 'Displaying Surveys {0} - {1} of {2}',
        emptyMsg: "No Surveys to display"
    }),

    stripeRows: true,
    trackover: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

and this is my store

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    storeId: 'myData',
    scope: this,
    fields: [{
        name: 'Q1',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'Q2',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'Q3',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'Q4',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'Q5',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'Improvements',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'Comments',
        type: 'string'
    }],

    sorters: [{
        property: 'Q1',
        direct: 'ASC'
    }],

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'GridView/writeRecord',
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            root: 'myTable',
            totalProperty: 'count'

        })
    }    
});
```

[And my Json looks like this, please click here](http://i45.tinypic.com/s15b0o.jpg)

**UPDATE** JSON RESULT

```
{
"count": 30,
"myTable": [
{
  "Q1": "1",
  "Q2": "1",
  "Q3": "1",
  "Q4": "1",
  "Improvements": "",
  "Comments": "1"
},
{
  "Q1": "1",
  "Q2": "2",
  "Q3": "3",
  "Q4": "4",
  "Improvements": "Iphone5",
  "Comments": "Iphone14"
},
{
  "Q1": "1",
  "Q2": "1",
  "Q3": "3",
  "Q4": "3",
  "Improvements": "This is Comment1-3",
  "Comments": "This is Comment2-3"
},
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the data you're returning from server. With that store configuration you must return a json formatted like this (note that records fields are different that yours)

```
{
"success" : true,
"count"   : 2,
"myTable" :[{
    "id"   : 1,
    "cod"  :"100001"
    },{
    "id"   : 2,
    "cod"  :"100001"
    }]
}
```

Store's root parameter is where extjs expects to have the array of records, success parameter is something you can handle to display server comunication errors and totalProperty is where you tell to extjs how many total records you have fetched. (Answer based on extjs 4.x, but as i can remember with 3.x is the same)

Comment: I see... so the whole json.net serialization does not produce json formatted data??? thanks charlie... if you have time, could you please see the accepted answer on this page..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608637/return-count-and-data-as-json-into-extjs-grid... this is how I encode my json.

Comment: Hey Charlie, I updated my post with the Json result... it looks pretty much the same and I checked with jsonlint to verify it's a valid json...any insight?

Comment: it looks correct (assuming that the missing curly ans square brackets at the end have been cutted while posting). You could easily debug if the store is loading correctly by attaching a listener with `console.log(store.getRange());` at store'sload event.

Comment: yeah... it's cut because there are like 30 records in the db... I think the store is loading right, cause the grid shows all the data... its just that the paging toolbar is not going to next page

Comment: I don't know why, looks correct. I don't have a full view on your code structure, maybe (only guessing) the "store" variable isn'accessible inside from toolbar? I think you could check if `bbar.store` is valorized.